# What should we do with [avg]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt

The [avg](/questions/tagged/avg) tag wiki excerpt says this:

> Anti-Virus Guard (AVG) is a family of anti-virus and Internet security software for the Microsoft Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, and FreeBSD computing platforms.

But a quick sampling of the questions shows this:

- [Trying to get averages from multiple columns here but all the values print as 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616600/trying-to-get-averages-from-multiple-columns-here-but-all-the-values-print-as-0)
- [Need to calculate the average of cost based on a per fiscal week basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600814/need-to-calculate-the-average-of-cost-based-on-a-per-fiscal-week-basis)
- [(MYSQL) Calculate average from a list of pupils who have some qualifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042523/mysql-calculate-average-from-a-list-of-pupils-who-have-some-qualifications)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848438/gnuplot-4-6-and-the-use-of-average
- [How do you determine the average total of a column in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387938/how-do-you-determine-the-average-total-of-a-column-in-postgresql)

The excerpt says it's for antivirus software, but a sampling of the questions shows it's used as a tag for questions about averages.

Should we retag (240 questions, so it's manageable) the bad uses, or should we edit the excerpt and make a new tag for the currently-legit uses?

Comment: For future reference, you can use related tags to identify the common context for tags like this very quickly, and construct [a search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avg+-sql+-sql-server+-sql-server-2008+-sqlite+-sql-server-2005+-sqlite3+-sql-server-2008-r2+-sqlalchemy+-sql-update+-sql-server-2012+-sql-server-ce+-sql-order-by+-sql-server-2000+-sql-injection+-sql-azure+-sql-server-express+-sqlplus+-sqldatasource+-sql-insert+-sqldatareader+-mysql) that narrows down the list to the most ambiguous questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The majority of these are related to the SQL `avg()` function. Almost all of the rest are connected to average calculations in other languages.

8 questions were actually related to AVG *the antivirus software* - mostly about how it was interfering with various development tools. I just retagged those to [antivirus](/questions/tagged/antivirus).

2 questions were in regards to [libavg](/questions/tagged/libavg) - so I just created that tag for them.

The rest of these have been merged into [average](/questions/tagged/average), with [avg](/questions/tagged/avg) made a synonym of that.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, we should retag all the questions about averages to [average](/questions/tagged/average).

Comment: This is just an answer for voting purposes, feel free to downvote or post another answer if your opinion is different.

Comment: That's a whole other problem, right?

Comment: There might be developer questions related to AVG.  You have to look at the questions on a case-by-case basis.